# Prepend to all image URLs with PHP, only for mobile devices

Tags: php, images, urls, cdn

Is there a way, with PHP, to prepend my CDN service's URL to all of my images only when using a mobile device?

The reason I ask to do it with PHP is because my site is AMP compatible, which doesn't allow me to use JS to do it.

Comment: php is agnostic about the browser, why not to serve always images from CDN instead of 'only when using a mobile device'?

Comment: That makes sense, the problem is I already have hundreds of posts with many more hundreds of photos on my site and I didn't want to go through each post and edit the URLs manually.

Comment: I'd expect most CDN integration plugins would update all of the URLs for you

Comment: They do, but the one I use does it with JS and AMP pages do not allow custom JS